# Git merging 2 branches not affecting all modified files

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, git-merge

I'm working on a project with a team member and we just met a weird problem that we don't how to investigate and solve.

Basically all the team works on branch A, and he created a branch B out of A like a month ago.

(Adding this info although I don't think it shpuld matter) 
We are working on a local repo that we created using git bare option

Lets assume that the amount of work he did on branch B since then equals 5x.
While time passed, he merged branch be into A about 2 times so we know like 3x of his work present in A.

Today we wanted to merge B into A again for the last time and get the remaining 2x of work into A and close B.

When we merged B into A we had 3 cases:

1. some files that were changed in both branches h were marked as conflicts. All good so here
2. some files that he changed in B wete correctly also updated in A which is good
3. some files that he made important changed 2 in B were not effected in A! Again, this files werent marked as conflicts by git.

We dont know why case 3 is happening. The x amount of work is a lot and thats why I used the word "some" all the time because we can't tell what happened to all the files he changed because there are to many.

Any suggestions to why this could happen or how we could use git to further investigate this odd scenario will be helpful

Comment: Mostly an aside: *We are working on a local repo that we created using git bare option* You literally can't work on/in a bare repo. That's the whole point of `--bare`: it has no work-tree. The work-tree is where you do your work, so without a work-tree, you have no place to do work. This makes a `--bare` repo a good place to *push* to, because it's hard (for good reason) to push to a repo when it has some branch checked out in its work-tree. So normally you just use these as targets for push, and make more clones from them and work in those other clones.

Comment: I think he means their remote is a local bare

Comment: MrKekson is right, the remote is bare, the working repo is a clone of it

Answer (score 1):

1: conflicts can happens, either merge them with a proper tool, like [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/), [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/), or by hand selecting the proper lines between

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
from A
=======
from B
>>>>>>> branch-b
```

2: good :d

3: not shure what happened, but a fev things come in mind: 
    he forgot to `push` them to the remote(bare) repo, 
    you forgot to `pull` from the bare, 
    both results in your local repo is behind in commits

if you `git diff A..B`, or `git diff --name-only A..B` you have to see all differences, if it's not there, then just push/pull

you can also `git checkout B`, then `git log`, and you must see the commits he made if everything is in sync

Comment: We did the merging in hus computer so branch B is updated. Also made sure the last changed to branch A were pulled and appeared correct in his pc, so its not a case of forgetting to pull anything. I will check tomorrow about the diff but to be completely honest im not sure what to look for

Comment: Ok, did he properly added and committed the files? Can you see it on "git status", or "git diff" if it's not staged, maybe "git diff --staged" if it is staged, but not committed?

Comment: Also, with access to hes repo, you can "git reflog" to se what happened in that repo.